# Any benefits in using TCP for desktop, when server already using WebSockets for web

Tags: .net, tcp, websocket, client-server

We're developing system which consists now of server written in .Net and web client. They are connected via websockets.

In future, I'd like to add desktop client to this system. Is there any point to use TCP for connection between desktop client and server, when I already have websocket implementation for web and I can use it for desktop too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

- WebSockets connections starts as a HTTP request, so it will go through firewalls easier than a socket connnection.
- WebSockets starts as HTTP but they behave like a regular TCP connection.
- Also, most of the times the same TCP port for HTTP is used for WebSockets, since that despite of  being a different protocol, the negotiation starts as HTTP.
- The WebSocket protocol defines already a way a framing data with little overhead.
- WebSockets supports transport security TLS
- WebSockets supports gzip message compression, although not all browsers do.
- But, if you want to implement your own super compression algorithm for use it only for the desktop clients, you can. Just configure it as a WebSocket extension, standard browsers will never ask for that extension.

I don't see the point of enabling a raw TCP connection if you have already WebSocket support.